# JQGrid: Sorting & Custom formatters

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

So I have a jqgrid, and I use custom formatters to format the collumns, anyway when I click on a collumn head to sort, it sorts the collumns as expected but it removes the formatting I did, and instead puts "[object Object]" into the collumns where the formatter should have done its work.

The particular formatter is:

```
function(cellVal, options, rowObject){
    var optsURI = '../webrelease/common/images/page_v2_u'+(rowObject.opt2Up==2?1:0)+'_s'+(rowObject.optDuplex?1:0)+'_c'+(rowObject.optColor?1:0)+'_52.png';
    return $('<img class="finishing_icon" height="40" src="'+optsURI+'" />').attr('jobid', rowObject.jobid).click(finishingOptsCycle);
}
```

This seems to work well for removing and adding rows, but as soon as I hit resort the collumn changes from an image to a string [object Object]

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

for completeness here is my entire jqgrid (excl rows & formatter):

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    editurl: "clientArray",
    width: 680,
    height: 290,
    colNames: [...],
    colModel: [...],
    hidegrid: false,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    multiselect: true,
    scroll:1,
    loadui: "block",
    loadtext: "Loading job list...",
    caption: 'Job List <img class="refreshbutton" width="20" height="20" src="../webrelease/desktop/images/icon_circle_arrow_right.png" />',
    pager: '#jqgrid_pager',
    onSelectRow: rowSelect,
    onSelectAll: allRowsSelect
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the wrong usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter). The function which implements custom formatter must return **string**.

I don't recommend you to assign `id` attribute to elements of grid if it is not really required. I don't understand why you could need to have `<img>` with ids.

If you need implement some custom action on click on the cell with `<img>` you can better use `onCellSelect` callback.

If you net yet implemented `unformat` for the same column where you use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) I recommend you to do this.

Comment: The id enabled the finishingOptsCycle function to look where the event was called from and work out what uniquely identifies the image. Cheers for the help.

Comment: @jezternz: Every event handler has [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) as the first parameter. Let us you declare if as variable `e`, then you can use `var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");` or better `var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow");` to get the `<tr>` element from the row. So `$tr.attr("id")` get you the `id` of the row where the click is fire. Having the rowid you can use `getCell` to get the content from any column or use `getRowData` if you need the values from all column of the row. So setting of additional `id` on `<img>` is not really required.

Comment: Yeh I certainly understand where you are coming from and see the merit, I guess my initial reasoning was probably that by adding an 'id', I don't need to ask for jquery dom traversal and an extra getCell call to retrieve my 'jobid'. I think $(this).attr('jobid'); just seems a lot simpler.

Comment: @jezternz: Potential problem with `id` attribute is very simple: the value must be unique on the whole page. Its difficult to guaranty that. If `jobid` are already used as rowid or if you have two rows with the same `jobid` or if you have the same `jobid` value somewhere else of the same page you would have problems. So you should place `id` attributes only if it's *really* required. If you really need to save some additional information in the HTML element you can use attribute which name starts with `data-` like `data-jobid`. Only `id` attribute must be unique.